# How to get a string that match from a data frame?

Tags: r

I have this data frame ("yt"), I want to create a string that will get the second column of the data frame only if "best" string match the first column of "yt".
 I tried this loop but it is not the way probably.. How can I do it?

```
rr<- c("ATR(HLC(x))","SMI(HLC(x))")
tt<- c("myATR","mySMI")
best<- c( "mySMI","myMFI" , "runMean.Cl")
yt<-data.frame(tt,rr,stringsAsFactors=F)
diti<- vector()
for (i in 1:length(best)){
 if(best[i]==yt[,1])  diti<- c(diti,yt[i,2]) 
}
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: You can use `%in%` i.e. `yt$tt %in% best` to get a logical index.,`yt$rr[yt$tt %in% best]`

Comment: akrun I still don't understand how to do it.. I want that like in the example above that "diti" will print: "SMI(HLC(x))". how the loop supposed to be?

Comment: You don't need a loop. The code is vectorized `diti <- yt$rr[yt$tt %in% best]`

Comment: Thanks, thats works!